# SoftLayer API: can you filter relational properties (objectMask)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to filter with an object mask?  I would like to get unattached portable storage.  I thought I could search portable storage volumes where the blockDeviceCount is 0 or blockDevices is null but have not been able to get either one to work.  The queries below return all storage volumes regardless of whether they have block devices.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/PortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes":{"blockDevices":{"operation":"is null"}}}&objectMask=mask[blockDeviceCount,blockDevices]

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/PortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes":{"blockDeviceCount":{"operation":"0"}}}&objectMask=mask[blockDeviceCount,blockDevices]
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this request:

```
https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumesobjectMask=mask[storageRepository[guests]]
```

basically all portable storage which does not have any sotrageRepository and the sotrageRepository does not have any guest, that means that portable storage is not attached.

Now you need to use your own code to filter the data, because using objectFilters there is not way to filter the data.

Regards

Comment: Hi Nelson, Thank you.  To clarify, can you ever filter on the 'Relational & Count Properties'?  Or are objectFilters only available for the 'Local properties' (i.e.the properties listed on the left side of the page when you view the DataType help page in the doc: https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Account)

Comment: The object filters do not work with all the data, for the case of the counters those values do not exist in the database they are worked out when you perform a request querying about those data.  For the case of arrays the filters are not capable to view if the array is empty or null. So there are many cases in what the filters Will not work in those cases you Will need to use your own code to filter the data